# Want to revert back previous field value

Tags: apex, batch

how to get the previous 'LastName' field values for Standard object Lead?

```
global class UpdateLeadBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    global final String Query;
    global final String Entity;
    global final String Field;
    global final String Value;

    global UpdateLeadBatch( String q, String e, String f, String v ){
        Query = q;
        Entity = e;
        Field = f;
        Value = v;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext BC ){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }
    global void execute( Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
        for( SObject s : scope ){
            s.put(Field , Value);
        }
        update scope;

    }
    global void finish( Database.BatchableContext BC ){

    }

}
```

and code to call the above class:

```
String q = 'select LastName from Lead limit 50';
String e = 'Lead';
String f = 'LastName';
String v = f + 'update';

UpdateLeadBatch uLB = new UpdateLeadBatch(q,e,f,v);
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(uLB, 5);
```

Comment: Do you have [field history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US) turned on for Lead.LastName? Otherwise there will be no record of the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [field history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US), the batchable would look something like this:

```
public class PreviousLeadLastNameBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                select Id, (
                        select OldValue
                        from Histories
                        order by CreatedDate desc, Id desc
                        limit 1
                        )
                from Lead
                ]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> scope) {
        SObject[] updates = new SObject[] {};
        for (Lead l : scope) {
            if (l.Histories.size() > 0) {
                // Previous value
                l.LastName = (String) l.Histories[0].OldValue;
                updates.add(l);
            }
        }
        update updates;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```